# Wailt until grpc::Server threads exit

Tags: c++, visual-studio, grpc

I can't understand behavior of uninitializing of gRPC server.

More precisely, I don’t understand why these four gRPC threads still exist(while I'm on line 52, after `server_` uninitialized and out from the scope.

My simplest example:
[image]
In gRPC source code I saw that `grpc::Server::ShutDown()` method(line 42) set `ThreadManager::shutdown_` to `true` and `grpc::Server::Wait()`(line 43) come into `condition_variable::Wait()` until all threads exit, but in my case I see different behavior.

How is it possible? Maybe I misunderstand something? How I can wait until this threads exit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server shutdown waits for the completion of threads associated with executing RPCs at the gRPC synchronous server but there are other threads created by gRPC at different times for other purposes (e.g., name resolver, timer). So those may be the threads that you're seeing. You'd have to know where those threads were created or what code they are executing to tell for sure. Those other threads will get shutdown at some point as part of the overall library shutdown (which only happens when all the gRPC API objects are freed).